# What is a proper way to create a JS promise that is rejected?

Tags: es6-promise

If just for experimenting with JS Promises or Promise.race(), etc, a promise that is rejected needs to be created:

```
p = Promise.reject(Error("some unknown reason"));
```

but this way, an exception will be thrown. And if you silent the error:

```
p = Promise.reject(Error("some unknown reason")).catch(err => {});
```

Then `p` actually will be a resolved promise. Why is that?  Is a rejected promise supposed to be created this way, or what should be done?  A resolved promise is much simpler if by using `Promise.resolve(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way to create a rejected promise would just be this:

```
let p = Promise.reject(new Error("some unknown reason"));
```

Somewhere, before you return back to the event loop, you will NEED to have a `.catch()` handler on any rejected promise.  If you don't, the system will warn you of an unhandled rejection.  That is the state of the Javascript language implementations.  The designers feel like it is extremely important to not let unhandled promise rejections slide by unnoticed (I agree - just like unhandled synchronous exceptions don't slide by unnoticed).  And, with the current state of the JS engines, their detection of an unhandled rejection is slightly imperfect.  It's possible you may do something with that rejected promise that LATER adds a `.catch()` handler, but the JS engine doesn't know you're doing to do it later.  It just knows that you've gotten back to the event loop and you didn't do it yet.  That seems like trouble so it warns you.

If you put a `.catch()` on it, then the promise takes on whatever you return or throw from the `.catch()` handler (just like a `try/catch` in the synchronous world).  So, if you do this:

```
let p = Promise.reject(new Error("some unknown reason")).catch(err => {});
```

Then, you catch the rejection in your `.catch()` and return or throw nothing from it, so the promise chain is now resolved with an `undefined` resolved value.  There is no requirement for a `.catch()` there, but if you have a specific reason to add a `.catch()` (such as logging or cleanup code or inspecting the error to determine proper course of action), but you want the promise chain to stay rejected with the same reason, then you must either return a new rejected promise or throw the original error like this:

```
let p = Promise.reject(new Error("some unknown reason")).catch(err => {
    // do whatever you want here
    console.log(err);
    throw err;                 // rethrow to keep the promise chain rejected
});
```

or like this:

```
let p = Promise.reject(new Error("some unknown reason")).catch(err => {
    // do whatever you want here
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);  // return rejected promise to keep the promise chain rejected
});
```

but, you need to DO something with that promise to use it in some sort of promise chain context that will eventually have a real `.catch()` handler.

For example (you mentioned Promise.race), you can do this just fine:

```js
function delay(t,v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

let p1 = Promise.reject(new Error("You got rejected!!"));
let p2 = delay(100, "Got a good result");

Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Here there would be no warnings about an unhandled promise rejection because we inserted the `p1` promise (that is rejected) into a `Promise.race()` and that has a `.catch()` handler on it.

> Then p actually will be a resolved promise. Why is that?

Because you had an empty `.catch()` that didn't return a rejected promise from the handler or didn't throw an exception.  So, the reject was "caught" and "handled" and the promise chain is now back to resolved.  Since there was no return value from the `.catch()` handler, the resolved value for the promise chain is now `undefined`.

> Is a rejected promise supposed to be created this way, or what should be done?

Yes, that is the proper way to create a rejected promise.  But, you need to DO something with it, not just let it sit there on its own.  And what ultimately gets done with it (returning it from some promise chain or linking other handlers onto it) needs to happen soon (like before the interpreter gets back to the event loop).  We could advise much better how to handle this if you presented a real world use case with real code.

Comment: I see... so it is a little harder to test on the Node console or Google Chrome's console... because once you type in `p = Promise.reject(Error("some unknown reason"));` and press Enter, then the exception is thrown... but I guess you can ignore it if it is during testing out

Comment: @nopole - Yes, you have to run code that uses it at the same time.  I use jsFiddle.net or nodejs with a temp.js play file to test stuff out all the time.  Easier for me to write some code and run it rather than typing lines in one at a time in the console as they run.

Comment: I also copied your Promise.race example into Google Chrome or Node console as one copy-and-paste, and no exception was thrown for some reason...  so `p1`'s exception was not handled but Promise.race() created a new promise and that exception was handled... and it is ok?

Comment: @nopole - `Promise.race()` handled the `p1` exception (it has to monitor both resolve and reject for any promise you pass it in order to do its job properly), passed it onto the promise that `Promise.race()` returns which was handled by the `.catch()` on it.  It was not left unhandled.

Comment: @nopole - FYI, here's a simple little [polyfill for `Promise.race()`](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/11010768#file-promise-js-L118) that shows you how it works and shows you that it monitors both the resolve handler and the reject handler for every promise you pass it.  It does it with two arguments to `.then(fn1, fn2)` instead of a `.catch()` for the reject which is also a perfectly fine way to do it.

Comment: oh just 4 lines (not including closing braces)... so each passed in promise will invoke the resolve and reject of the new promise, so that's why the rejected `p2` is considered "caught". So these 2 lines are ok both in Node and Chrome: `let p1 = Promise.reject(new Error("You got rejected!!"));
let p2 = p1.catch(err => {});`

Comment: @nopole - I don't understand why you write `p1.catch(err => {});`.  That's just hiding a rejected promise.  If you had a run-time error in the code that leads to that promise and it threw a TypeError or something like that, you'd never know what happened because you just "ate" that error silenty.  I don't think I would EVER write `p1.catch(err => {});` in my code.  It's just too easy to silenty eat some error you need to know about.  But, yes that will keep nodejs from complaining about an unrejected promise because you "caught" the rejection.

Comment: @nopole - IMO, every promise rejection should be caught and at least logged.  And pass rejections up to higher levels.  So, if you want catch it and log it at a lower level, you rethrow so the higher level can see it.  Even something simple like an error closing a file that there's nothing really useful to do if that fails, I'm still going to log it because it could be the sign of something wrong in the system or could be the precursor to some larger problem or could just indicate a fault in the code (like trying to close a file that never got opened).

Comment: that line `p1.catch(err => {})` was just to test the situation: if rejected promise has a catch(), then at the end of event cycle there would be no complaint. What about if it is Ajax to fetch something and the user lost Internet connection? I would show a red label saying, "network error. Please try again later" on screen, but I noticed many websites just "let it be"... no error statement whatsoever, but the user probably will know because none of their webpage can be refreshed. When you say "log the error" do you mean if the JS is running as server code or as a desktop app?

Comment: @nopole - I was talking about server logging.  But client code needs logging during development and testing that can perhaps be turned off when deployed (that depends upon the app).  If the user in a client is trying to accomplish some task that results in an Ajax call and that Ajax call fails, then the user should likely be notified of some sort of non-completion of the activity with some reason why.  If it's some client background updating that fails, then that's up to the app and user experience designers what to do there.